# Proof critique on theorem involving function compositions

Tags: functions

Problem statement, as written:

Let $g\colon B\rightarrow C$ and $h\colon B\rightarrow C$ be functions. Suppose that $g\circ f = h\circ f$ for every function $f\colon A\rightarrow B$. Prove that $g=h$.

Supose, to the contrary, that $g\ne h$. Then there is some $b_0 \in B$ such that $g(b_0) \ne h(b_0)$. Let $f_0\colon A\rightarrow B$ be a surjective function. Then $\exists a_0\in A$ such that $b_0 = f(a_0)$. As such, since $g\circ f_0 = h\circ f_0$ by hypothesis, $g(f(a_0)) = g(b_0) = h(f(a_0)) = h(b_0)$. This implies, in particular, that $g(b_0) = h(b_0)$, a contradiction. Hence, it must be the case that $g=h$.

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct. You cannot assume that there is a surjective map from $A$ onto $B$ since, in general, there isn't (it exists if and only if $|A|\geqslant|B|$).

If $A$ is empty, the statement is false. Otherwise, consider the constant map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&A&\longrightarrow&B\\&a&\mapsto&b_0.\end{array}$$Take $a_0\in A$. Then $(g\circ f)(a_0)\ne(h\circ f)(a_0)$ and therefore $g\circ f\ne h\circ f$.

Comment: If we suppose the composition equality is true for EVERY function, $f$, mustn’t it be true when $A = \emptyset$ (and, hence, $f = \emptyset$) too? 

I see why your particular case could result in $g\ne h$, but the theorem states that the implication holds for ALL potential $f$. I’m trying to devise a general proof independent of considering A empty or not. Is this possible? If not, there should certainly be mention that $A \ne \emptyset$ in the problem statement, I would think.

Comment: I read the problem as follows: given three sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ and two functions $g,h\colon B\longrightarrow C$, prove that $g=h$ if and only if, for every function $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$, $g\circ f=h\circ f$. Under this interpretation, the statement is false if $A=\emptyset$. Otherwise, it is true and my proof holds.

Comment: Maybe that’s the problem. As I interpreted, the first statement of the problem only fixes $B$ and $C$. $A$ is introduced later, under universal quantification. 

Your interpretation I like better, and results in a possible proof. The book I’m working in seems to be careless in this chapter’s exercise statements.

Comment: If you are free to choose $A$, then just take $A=B$ and $f(b)=b$ for each $b\in B$.

Comment: I think that’s what I needed, thanks ! How does this look: Supose, to the contrary, that $g\ne h$. Then there is some $b_0 \in B$ such that $g(b_0) \ne h(b_0)$. Let $f_0\colon A=B\rightarrow B$ be defined by $f_0(b) = b, b\in B$. Then $b_0 = f_0(b_0)$. As such, since $g\circ f_0 = h\circ f_0$ by hypothesis, $g(f_0(b_0)) = g(b_0) = h(f_0(b_0)) = h(b_0)$. This implies, in particular, that $g(b_0) = h(b_0)$, a contradiction. Hence, it must be the case that $g=h$.

Comment: Under the interpretation that you are free to choose $A$, that is a correct proof indeed.