# Proof check involving compositions of functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This is a somewhat similar question to the one I posted earlier [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667731/proof-critique-on-theorem-involving-function-compositions/3667737?noredirect=1#comment7537248_3667737). I think I understand the full utility of the statement "for every pair of functions..." now. The universal quantification over the functions applies implicitly to the set(s) the functions act on too, if they haven't priorly been fixed. I also suspect an error in the problem statement- namely, that "if $B\ne \emptyset$ then A $\ne \emptyset$" must be included, otherwise contradiction may be reached; in particular, in the $(\leftarrow)$ direction, one would have to prove $f$ to be surjective, an impossible task if $f\colon \emptyset \rightarrow B$, where $B \ne \emptyset$. I'm posting to confirm this contention, whilst having my proof (which assumes this presumed omission) critiqued as well.

Problem statement, as written:

Let $f\colon A \rightarrow B$ be a function. Prove that $f$ is surjective if and only if, for every pair of functions $g,h\colon B \rightarrow C$, if $g\circ f = h\circ f$, then $g=h$. [I am contending the theorem must be preceded with the statement, "If $B \ne \emptyset$, then $A \ne \emptyset$."]

Proof: $(\rightarrow)$ Suppose $f$ is surjective. Let $g,h\colon B\rightarrow C$ and assume $g\circ f = h\circ f$. Now, suppose (to the contrary) $g\ne h$. Then there exists some $b_0 \in B$ such that $g(b_0)\ne h(b_0)$. Since $f$ is surjective, there is some $a_0\in A$ such that $f(a_0) = b_0$. Note $(g\circ f)(a_0) = g(f(a_0)) = g(b_0)$. Likewise,  $(h\circ f)(a_0) = h(f(a_0)) = h(b_0)$. Since $g\circ f = h\circ f\colon A\rightarrow C$ by hypothesis and $(a_0,h(b_0)),(a_0,g(b_0))\in g\circ f = h\circ g$, this implies $h(b_0) = g(b_0)$. But this is a direct contradiction to  $g(b_0)\ne h(b_0)$ above. Hence, it must be the case that $g = h$ indeed.

$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose for every pair of functions $g,h\colon B\rightarrow C$, if $g\circ f = h\circ f$, then $g=h$. Now suppose (to the contrary) $f$ is not surjective. That is, there is some $b_0\in B$ such that, for all $a\in A, f(a) \ne b_0$. [The following makes use of my added premise noted in the problem statement; it seems one would be stuck from here, otherwise] Since $B\ne \emptyset$, $A\ne \emptyset$ by hypothesis. As such, let $a_0\in A$. Then $f(a_1) = b_1 \in B$, where $b_1 \ne b_0$. Define $g\colon B\rightarrow C=B$ by $g(b)=b_1, g\in B$ and $h\colon B\rightarrow C=B$ by $h = \{(b,b_1)|b\in (B - \{b_0\})\} \cup \{(b_0,b_0)\}$. Now, let $\alpha \in A$ be arbitrary. Then $(g\circ f)(\alpha) = g(f(\alpha)) = h(f(\alpha)) = (h\circ f)(\alpha) = b_1$. The particular equality $g(f(\alpha)) = h(f(\alpha))$ holds by the definition of $h$; to clarify, because $f(\alpha) \ne b_0$ by hypothesis, so $f(\alpha) \in (B - \{b_0\})$. Thus, we have shown that $g\circ f = h\circ g$, which implies, by hypothesis, that $g=h$. But this is clearly a contradiction, as $g\ne h$ since, in particular, $g(b_0) = b_1 \ne b_0 = h(b_0)$. Hence, $f$ must, in fact, be surjective. Q.E.D.